# setVolumeControlStream() in a multiple activity application

Tags: android, audio, stream, controls, volume

I've got three activities in my application and I have problems with calling the above mentioned method. First of all, do I have to call it inside every activity's onCreate() method? Right now I've tried it this way, and suddenly it works only in one activity of three. In other two the default volume control bar is not shown and the volume is not adjusted. What's the right way of controling volume stream in a multiple activity application? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have overriden onKeyDown() etc make sure that you do call super.onKeyDown() as well for keys that you do not handle or at least for the volume up/down keys, e.g. in your view subclass:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   // do your stuff here...
   if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)) {
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }   
    return true;
}
```